# received error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" after add in if condition in .map (Reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im new in reactjs and I am having an issue which is, I am receiving an error after I add in the if condition in .map

what i want to do is, if the data is null it will return the marker else don't display marker

error:

```
/src/component/Map.js
  Line 47:17:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

```
return (
    <div>
      <MapGL
        {...viewport}
        width="100vw"
        height="100vh"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10"
        onViewportChange={setViewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      >

      {Object.keys(sigfox).map(({id, device, lat, lon}) => {
        if(lat !== null && lon !== null)
          return  
                <Marker
                key={id}
                latitude={lat}
                longitude={lon}
                >
                  <div style={{color: "yellow"}}>
                      {device}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <GoLocation style={{color: "pink"}}/>
                  </div>
                </Marker>
        return null
        }
      )}

      </MapGL>
    </div>

  );
```

please help! thank you very much :)

Comment: You could just use an else before the ``` return null ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an error form you JSX linter, you have two return null, thats why you are having this error,

try this:

```
return (
  <div>
    <MapGL
      {...viewport}
      width="100vw"
      height="100vh"
      mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10"
      onViewportChange={setViewport}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    >
      {Object.keys(sigfox).map(({ id, device, lat, lon }) => {
        return (lat !== null && lon !== null) ? <Marker key={id} latitude={lat} longitude={lon}>
          <div style={{ color: "yellow" }}>{device}</div>
          <div>
            <GoLocation style={{ color: "pink" }} />
          </div>
        </Marker>
         : null
      })}
    </MapGL>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Glad it helped, please accept my it as answer, then! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will show the marker when you have the latitude and longitude.
you can change the condition as per your requirement.

```
         {Object.keys(sigfox).map(({ id, device, lat, lon }) => {
              return ilat && lon ? (
               <Marker
                key={id}
                latitude={lat}
                longitude={lon}
                >
                  <div style={{color: "yellow"}}>
                      {device}
                  </div>
                  <div>
                      <GoLocation style={{color: "pink"}}/>
                  </div>
                </Marker>
              ) 
             : null
            })}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, after i added in it still having the same error but it already been solved by mamoun othman's post. thanks again! :)